# The voting buttons are still displayed for historical elections

Tags: feature-request, election

When viewing historical election results, the voting buttons still appear as if it is still ongoing:

[image: Gaming Election with buttons still enabled]
<sup>*Also the second button is longer than the others :(</sup>

[image: voting not allowed]

There is a check in place to prohibit voting after the election has closed but from a UI point of view I think it's likely to be an accidental inclusion of the buttons.

Interestingly this only happens on some sites.  Stack Overflow and Seasoned Advice are not affected whilst [Gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/election/3?tab=election) and [Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/election/1?tab=election) are.

---

## Ah.  My Bad.

As I was posting this I worked out that it's not a bug at all and that they appear **retroactively** for all elections once you have enough reputation to vote on the site in question.  The candidates you voted for are still highlighted therefore if you didn't vote or were not eligible to, all the voting buttons are displayed for all of the candidates with none highlighted.

#### However

I don't think this is as clear as it could be.  I'd like to suggest the following changes:

- Don't show all the buttons for all the candidates.
- Instead display a icon only for the candidates you voted for:
  [image: Skeptics first choice button], for example
- **Don't make the buttons clickable**.